Saving region properties from skimage.measure to a pickle file raises RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
In my analysis code, I am performing some image properties analysis using skimage.measure.regionprops.
In order to save processing time, I would like to save the region properties to a file and I was thinking to use pickle as I often do.
Here is my piece of code.
import numpy as np
import pickle

from skimage.draw import ellipse
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops
from skimage.transform import rotate

# generate fake image
image = np.zeros((600, 600))

rr, cc = ellipse(300, 350, 100, 220)
image[rr, cc] = 1

image = rotate(image, angle=15, order=0)

rr, cc = ellipse(100, 100, 60, 50)
image[rr, cc] = 1

# find labels
label_img = label(image)

# calculate region props
regions = regionprops(label_img, image)

# save to pickle file
with open('test.sav', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(regions, f)

# reload it
with open('test.sav', 'rb') as f:
    saved_regions = pickle.load(f)

Saving to file is not a problem, but when I try to reload it, I get this error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bulghao\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.3\scratches\cosmic\save_2_file.py", line 31, in <module>
    saved_regions = pickle.load(f)
  File "C:\Users\bulghao\venv\autoradenv\lib\site-packages\skimage\measure\_regionprops.py", line 341, in __getattr__
    if self._intensity_image is None and attr in _require_intensity_image:
  File "C:\Users\bulghao\venv\autoradenv\lib\site-packages\skimage\measure\_regionprops.py", line 341, in __getattr__
    if self._intensity_image is None and attr in _require_intensity_image:
  File "C:\Users\bulghao\venv\autoradenv\lib\site-packages\skimage\measure\_regionprops.py", line 341, in __getattr__
    if self._intensity_image is None and attr in _require_intensity_image:
  [Previous line repeated 995 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

From what I guess, the intensity image was not saved or it was not possible to reload it.
My question is: is there a way to save regionprops to disk for future use?
I can save and reload the labels, but saving both would be much better.
EDIT:
Following Christoph Rackwitz comment below, we discovered that it is actually a bug of skimage and that an open issue on GitHub is showing exactly this problem. The issue is dormant, but a workaround has been suggested.

likely a bug. now you need to find out if it was fixed already or is still an issue: first make sure all the libraries are up to date (latest python for the pickle, latest skimage). if that still causes the issue, you get to report it to the skimage project. I don't see any issues mentioning this issue, so it's probably not fixed yet.

Thanks! I'm running skimage 0.21 (latest 0.24) and python 3.10.4 so actually not the newest. But in principle you think it should be working as I coded it, right?

I think I have found the issue on github: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/6465

that definitely looks like the issue you have. IDK why I didn't find that. -- I can't say whether serialization should have worked but the recursion error comes from their code and looks like a simple mistake.

I have implemented the workaround suggested and even though it is kind of patching, it fits for purpose. Should the issue being fixed in the next release, I will return to the original code
